# spring mvc hbase web application

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I just got a new job as a java developer, but my first assignment is making a web application using the spring framework. I've been doing research the past two days but I'm unsure of how to proceed because I have no web development experience. I need to make a web UI that selects certain rows from an hbase database based on a field from a drop down box. It needs to return a boolean field from the db (I guess as a checkbox on the html table that the user can edit) and should allow the user to update that field to true or false. I think my coworker is working on a java class that interfaces with the database. My question is, how does this specific class work with html/javascript/ajax/jdbc template? I'm extremely confused on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Get yourself a good book on Spring MVC, there are plenty to choose from, plus online resources. You need to work through a tutorial.

Comment: I did a simple mvc tutorial, but I'm unsure of how all the puzzles fit together because all the tutorials online are really simple.